# Schedule Query and Export

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, excel, jobs

Is it possible, to schedule a simple Query to run Daily and export the received data into an excel file?

Comment: How simple (row count, number of columns, etc.)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can easily be done through an SSIS package and scheduled with SQL Server Agent. See this link for a tutorial/demonstration on the task: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/402958/SSIS-Package-Export-Data-from-Database-Daily-to-Ne

Comment: ...and then see my answer [here](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/44607/2718) and switch to CSV/TSV. :)

Comment: +1 to @JonSeigel's comment.  In my opinion, ETL isn't the best process for "pretty" data.  Get it into the flat file and then if you need formatting (from Excel or any other formatting source) you can handle it after the fact.

Comment: Honestly I would have no problem using the Excel Destination if it worked reliably. The issue of component installation is a separate matter, and may be an obstacle as well.