# How do I access the full text of an error in SSIS GUI?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, ssis

I have an Excel task which is providing error text through the GUI, but I don't know how to access the error task without the GUI and the error disappears if I move the cursor from the X

[image]

I have the project property Run64BitRuntime set to False (though it is not editable so even if I wanted to, couldn't change it to true)

Comment: By the way, installing the accessDatabaseEngine resolved the issue.  While most people reporting this had 32bit office installed with no 64bit driver, I had 64bit installed with no 32 bit driver.  The Run64BitRuntime=Falso was causing SSIS to run the 32 bit office driver which was not installed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Design-time errors, warnings, and informational messages show up in the Error List pane, which can be shown by going to View | Error List.

[image]

Comment: I was really hoping this would solve my problem but alas... The Error List is empty even though I have a task with an Error emblem and the leading half of an error message in a tooltip

Comment: @APC, more than a year after your comment, I can confirm that design-time error messages are _still not shown_ in the error list in the latest versions of the tools (_Visual Studio Professional 2019 v 16.3.7_ with extension _SQL Server Integration Services Projects v 3.9_.

Comment: I manipulated a value in the Advanced Editor and now I'm getting Validation Warnings.  These are neither Warnings or Errors.